# Swapping EIDE for SATA

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I have an Acer laptop with an EIDE hard drive.  Can I replace it with a SATA drive?

Comment: that depends on "what model EXACTLY" you have and if that model has a dual interface for disk drives (which is something i doubt for 99%).

Comment: you could perhaps use an adaptor and perhaps have it hang out. but it wouldn't look pretty, or neat. and you'd have to be careful 'cos you wouldn't want a spinning disk drive knocking about while it runs!

Answer (score 3):

I would say no to be on the safe side.

Whilst for desktops it is possible to get adapters, there just is no room for them in laptops. IF the bay was only designed for IDE drives, it is much safer just to stick with an IDE drive.

Answer (score 1):

Except for a tiny number of laptops produced ages ago, you cannot install a SATA drive into a laptop that came with an IDE drive.  The only other exception would be a laptop that has two drive bays, one for SATA and one for IDE.  I highly doubt your laptop has two drive bays to begin with.

Laptop drive bays are designed to have the drive fit snugly into them.  There is only enough spare room to allow for removal of the drive.  Desktop SATA drive to IDE converter boards usually won't fit into laptop drive bays to begin with, so shrinking that package down so that not only will it all fit within the drive bay, but you're also able to remove it later on would be nearly impossible.

**Update**
After a quick search, I found [this](http://www.cooldrives.com/2sahadrtoide.html), which is pretty much exactly what your want, except that they say that it won't fit most laptops, and yours would be one that it won't fit into.

Comment: Many Thanks.  Looks like I'll have to find a suitable IDE drive then.